# custom Icon not displayed in mono application

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I have a mono application developed with MonoDevelop as IDE. I'm working with windows 7.
I set a custom icon (embedded into the .exe).
When I run my application from inside MonoDevelop, all is fine.

But when I manually run "mono.exe ", my custom icon does not appears in the windows task bar. Instead, it appears a -it seems to me- predefined one.

How can I get my custom icon visible also when running my application from the command line? Starting always from inside MonoDevelop is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: You say you're running it on windows, are you using GTK#?  
Can you attempt running it on any UNIX-like (e.g. Debian) to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your app from MonoDevelop, it runs using the .NET runtime. So Windows is able to pick up the app icon. When you run it using Mono, the executable app (from Windows' point of view) is Mono.exe. So you get Mono's icon.

I recommend that on Windows you run your app on .NET - even MonoDevelop runs on .NET on Windows. The Mono package for Windows is primarily intended for development (checking your app will run with Mono) and for specialized embedding purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do so in windows. But I also deploy my application in Linux/Ubuntu. Any suggestion how can I make my icon appear in linux? Thanks again.

Comment: App icons in linux are defined very differently. You will need to install the icon into the icon theme, and install an app shortcut (a *.desktop file) that references the icon by name.